# I want use the PUT method in order to update a variable on my database. I need to update that variable everytime a button is clicked

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, put

On my Index.cshtm I have two buttons, and if one of those buttons is clicked I want to update a property on my database. For exemple, I have a marker that has a state of "accepted", and when I click the infowindow of that marker I have the option to choose 2 states ("denied", "other"). If I press the button "denied", the state of that marker (that was previously "accepted") it will change to "denied" on my database. For that I'm using the PUT method and ajax on the client-side. However it gives me an error when I try to change the state of a marker. 
Here is the code on the client-side:

```
    function atualizaBD(newState) {
           $.ajax
        ({
            url: `/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify({

                State: newState
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('State Updated');

            },

            error: function () {
                alert("Error")
            }
        });
}
```

Here is the code of one of the buttons:

```
function denied() {
    var conclued = L.icon({
        iconUrl: ' https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/modifiers-essential-glyph-1/48/Mod_Essentials-24-256.png',
        iconSize: [35, 35]
    });

    if (clickedmarker) {
        clickedmarker.setIcon(denied);
    }
    clickedmarker = null;
    atualizaBD("denied");
    connection.invoke("PostMarker").catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
}
```

Here is the code of my controller:

```
 [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao, string newState)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (id != ignicao.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }


        var decisionDate= DateTime.Now;
        var ig = _context.Ignicoes.FirstOrDefault(ignicaoId => ignicaoId.Id.Equals(id));
        ig.State= newState;
        ig.Latitude = ignicao.Latitude;
        ig.Longitude = ignicao.Longitude;
        //esta data vai depender da avaliação de cada uma das ocorrencias 
        ig.DataInicioPropostaIgnicao = ignicao.DataInicioPropostaIgnicao;
        ig.DataDecisaoIgnicao = decisionDate;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!IgnicoesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you should confirm `${id}` in url is filled since the PUT action needs `id` in route . And you missed the `contentType` in ajax , set value to `application/json; charset=utf-8` if passing json string :

```
function atualizaBD(newState) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: `/api/IgnicoesAPI/5`, // pass {id} 
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({

            State: newState
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            alert('State Updated');

        },

        error: function () {
            alert("Error")
        }
    });
}
```

And on server side , you could define a model to accept values which sent from client if you want to send more data besides `State` , use `[FromBody]` for model binding :

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public void PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id,   [FromBody]myValue myValue)
{
   var state = myValue.State;
}

public class myValue {
   public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()", I'm not sure why

Comment: check the properties in your model class , are they  `public`  and have get; set; ?

Comment: yes it does. It's exactly how you have in the response above